# Nuxt doesn't update on route change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

When navigation to the different parameters of a page (`/category/a` to `/category/b`), Nuxt doesn't update the page

I have a page `/pages/category/_id` that loads data using `fetch`. On first load it works fine but when navigation to another category (using `nuxt-link`) the page doesn't update.

Fetch is triggered, but the content on the page is not updated. Url in browser is changed.

Here's a few things I've tried so far:

- Adding `watchQuery: ['id'],` and `watchQuery: ['page'],` (I thought page was a keyword)
- Adding a `:key` to the list rendering component on the page
- Both using `nuxt-link` and `$router.push` for navigation

I don't get any error message.

I want nuxt to treat this as going to another page. I was looking at using `beforeRouteUpdate` but then I manually have to do some updateing to the entire page.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide code of your `fetch` method?

Comment: @Krillko I face the same issue. What was your solution?

Comment: @FooBar I think I added :key to one of the child components, the page was updating but not the component. So I used the category id as key on the child components

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case it was with a specific page, e.g. "about.vue". But the issue was, that I already had a folder called "about", so basically my folder structure looked like this:

```
pages/about.vue
pages/about/index.vue
```

So make sure you look at your `pages/` structure.